# Pyinstaller, how to make 32bit and 64bit .exe on 32bit linux?

Tags: windows-7, python-2.7, 32bit-64bit, exe, pyinstaller

I created executable using pyinstaller 2.0 and python2.7 on ubuntu 12.04 32bit (so I assume python is also 32bit).

It's a simple program in console (no gui), that connects to TCP/IP server and send frames.
It works under my ubuntu 32bit, but it does not run on Windows 7 32bit and 64bit. 
On Win32bit it returns error "Device is not ready", and on Win64bit it returns error that "application has wrong architecture".

Where can be cause of this?

Here is a link to whole app code (it's small) http://pastebin.com/qj96vpgK

Comment: The title of this question indicates how to create an executable for windows on 32bit linux. That has little to do with the problem, which might have to do with the portability of the low level socket module. To test run your code without knowing what kind of server is expected on port 1204 on machine 192.168.0.160 was kind of difficult. I get '[ERROR] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond' on a fresh WinXP install.

Comment: Your have to build for each system separately, on the system that the packaged app is supposed to run on. For you question it is not clear whether you did that, or tried to run the Unbuntu package on Windows, which is guaranteed not to word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Linux version of PyInstaller can not make `.exe`s or any non-Linux-native format. In order to make a Windows executable, you need to either use WINE (or at least they [say](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/FAQ#Features), but I'm not sure how to do that), or use a Windows computer.

Additionally, if the Windows computer you use is 32-bit, it can not make 64-bit binaries. If you have a 64-bit install of Windows, it can make 64-bit binaries easily, but in order to make 32-bit ones, you need to install a 32-bit version of Python (and all the required libraries for your program).

Thus, one way to make both 32- and 64-bit executables for a given program, copy your code over to a Windows 64-bit OS, install the 32 and 64-bit Python and `pywin32`, and use PyInstaller using each different Python.